# BIND Slave Receiving Notify From Other Slave?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver, master-slave

I have a master nameserver setup with a few slaves as well. Today I was changing one of the slaves to a new server when I came accross a weird error message.
After updating the DNS records on the master and restarting BIND, I noticed that `ns3.mydomain.com` was trying to send `ns4.mydomain.com` a notify. I've checked the configuration files and no where does it have the IP address for `ns4.mydomain.com` in the `ns3.mydomain.com` configuration files.
Shouldn't it be `ns1.mydomain.com` sending the notify to `ns4` and not `ns3`? I should also note that the DNS records on both `ns3` and `ns4` seem to be updated.

Here's the error messages on ns3 (IP Address: `107.161.xxx.xxx`):

```
May 15 22:08:22 vps named[23851]: client 185.38.xxx.xxx#59396: received notify for zone 'mydomain1.com'
May 15 22:08:22 vps named[23851]: zone mydomain1.com/IN: refused notify from non-master: 185.38.xxx.xxx#59396
May 15 22:08:22 vps named[23851]: client 185.38.xxx.xxx#59396: received notify for zone 'mydomain2.com'
May 15 22:08:22 vps named[23851]: zone mydomain2.com/IN: refused notify from non-master: 185.38.xxx.xxx#59396
May 15 22:08:22 vps named[23851]: client 185.38.xxx.xxx#59396: received notify for zone 'mydomain3.com'
May 15 22:08:22 vps named[23851]: zone mydomain3.com/IN: refused notify from non-master: 185.38.xxx.xxx#59396
May 15 22:08:23 vps named[23851]: client 185.38.xxx.xxx#59396: received notify for zone 'mydomain4.com'
May 15 22:08:23 vps named[23851]: zone mydomain4.com/IN: refused notify from non-master: 185.38.xxx.xxx#59396
```

Here's the error messages on ns4 (IP Address: `185.38.xxx.xxx`):

```
May 15 22:08:22 uk named[572]: client 107.161.xxx.xxx#48742: received notify for zone 'mydomain1.com'
May 15 22:08:22 uk named[572]: zone mydomain1.com/IN: refused notify from non-master: 107.161.xxx.xxx#48742
May 15 22:08:22 uk named[572]: client 107.161.xxx.xxx#48742: received notify for zone 'mydomain2.com'
May 15 22:08:22 uk named[572]: zone mydomain2.com/IN: refused notify from non-master: 107.161.xxx.xxx#48742
May 15 22:08:22 uk named[572]: client 107.161.xxx.xxx#48742: received notify for zone 'mydomain3.com'
May 15 22:08:22 uk named[572]: zone mydomain3.com/IN: refused notify from non-master: 107.161.xxx.xxx#48742
May 15 22:08:22 uk named[572]: client 107.161.xxx.xxx#48742: received notify for zone 'mydomain4.com'
May 15 22:08:22 uk named[572]: zone mydomain4.com/IN: refused notify from non-master: 107.161.xxx.xxx#48742
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either specify [`notify master-only;`](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9.16.20/reference.html#boolean-options) in the `options` section or specify [`notify no;`](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9.16.20/reference.html#zone-options) in the slave `zone` definitions if you do not want notify messages to be sent.

Notify messages are by default sent to all the zone's nameservers (based on `NS` records in zone data) except that of `SOA` `MNAME` (also see `notify-to-soa`).

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to apply the `allow-notify { address_list };` statement in the options of slave zone name servers, where 'address_list' should be the source IP of master name server's notify message.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/xfer.html#notify) shows, if notifies are enabled then notify messages will be sent to every server listed in the NS records of that zone.  This applies to both masters and slaves.